# Double producing an odd output compared to float

Tags: c

I'd really like to know why this screws up my code when I use a double. From my understanding, a double is simply a more precise floating point number. Yet in the following code, if I replace float with double, I get a wacky output, even though all the code is doing is taking input, and spitting it back out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int y;
int z;
int i;
int n;
int r;
int c;
float e;
float d;

void main() {
    puts("Enter Row Number:");
    scanf("%i", &r);
    puts("Enter Column Number:");
    scanf("%i", &c);
    float x[r][c];
    int j = r;

    for(y = 1; y <= r; y++) {
        for(z = 1; z <= c; z++) {
            scanf("%f", &x[y][z]);
        }
    }
    for (y = 1; y <= r; y++) {
        for(z = 1; z <= c; z++) {
            printf("%g\t", x[y][z]);
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
}
```

In the instance of using float, after inputting 2 for the rows, and 3 for the columns, then the numbers 1-6, I get an output of 1-6, as expected. But with using double's instead, and keeping the input the same as before, I get an output of {1.36224e-312,1.78905e-307, 1.81506e-307, 3.15957e+263, 5.3568e-315, 3.44886e-313}. Obviously that's not even close to correct, and its not like I'm dealing with complex numbers here... Just whole numbers 1-6. What gives?

Comment: If you use double, you need to read input with `%lf`

Comment: When you define an array like `x[r][c]`, valid indices into that array are `0`..`r-1` and `0`..`c-1`.

Comment: I'm surprised that your code does not generate a segmentation fault since you are iterating from 1...r (r the size of the data structure) and in C the arrays and matrix are numbered 0...r-1

Comment: I think it doesn't generate segmentation fault because segmetns are much larger than a single float. It would trigger an error in some debugging environments like Microsoft Visual C, because it puts an extra space after each array to look at this kind of errors. But not in general case with each C compiler.

Comment: It was what nhahtdh said. I wasn't aware scanf needed a different argument for doubles. Jerry and Hernan, while both of you are correct, and I've noticed that before, for some reason it doesn't seem to generate any errors or cause any issues, so I've simply left it that way. Sloppy, I know. Thanks for the help, I'll answer my own question when I can

Answer (score 0):

`scanf %f` expects an address of a `float`. It is dangerous to read data with `scanf` directly to a variable which isn't local, because it's harder to see that it actually isn't a `float`. I would change the code this way to be more robust:

```
float temp;
scanf("%f", &temp);
x[y][x] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are wrong:

```
for(y = 1; y <= r; y++) {
    for(z = 1; z <= c; z++) {
```

When you define an array

```
float x[r][c];
```

the index of the array goes from zero to the size minus one. So the `y` limits of the `x` array is

```
x[0]  /* first sub-array */
x[r - 1]  /* last sub-array */
```

Change your loops to

```
for(y = 0; y < r; y++) {
    for(z = 0; z < c; z++) {
```

Note that they now start at zero, and uses the less-than comparison operator instead.